# JPA, HIBERNATE strange error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i dont know why im getting this error, i tryed a lot of different persistence.xml configs over the internet, but the error never change...

and in my classpath i have all the .jars from required folder from this hibernate download ( http://hibernate.org/orm/) and i downloaded the validator, i have everything in WebContent/web-inf/libs and the hibernate.xml is in the src/meta-inf....

what can be?

error:

```
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: cartorio
    ...]
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste]
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:50 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:50 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Fev 06, 2014 1:38:50 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.2.Final
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at jpahibernate.geraTabelas.main(geraTabelas.java:11)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/Filter
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:217)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

my persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">  
    <persistence-unit name="cartorio" transaction-type="JTA">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
    <class>jpahibernate.PessoaFisica</class>  
        <properties>  
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste" />  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />  
        </properties>  
     </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

Comment: that's not strange. it is `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Are you using hibernate.cfg.xml too ?

Comment: @VivekVermani no, just the persistence.xml

Comment: I assume having the missing jar should resolve the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101656/2459449).

Answer (score -1):

Simple class not found exception.  Read the error, fix the error.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.Filter

google pointed me to [Why is Hibernate 4.2 using jandex and classmate if its Maven POM defines them as test scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168365/why-is-hibernate-4-2-using-jandex-and-classmate-if-its-maven-pom-defines-them-as)