# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when marking a jar as provided

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, packaging

I have the follwing dependency in my webapp:

```
<!-- swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${version.swagger.springmvc}</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to reduce the size of the war file so I marked the swagger jar as provided:

```
<!-- swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${version.swagger.springmvc}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added the swagger jar to tomcat's common lib folder so it should be provided by tomcat during runtime, but when i try to deply the app I got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:368)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:348)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:421)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:456)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:118)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:358)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
... 36 more
```

I notice that the problem is comming from the org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses but i have all the spring jar required declared in my pom without the provided scope also when
running the webapp without the provided scope it work fine any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue comes from another missing jar.
In the stacktrace we see

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver
```

The com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver is present in the jar classmate.jar, which is a dependency from swagger-springmvc.

When you use scope compile, the dependencies of swagger-springmvc are deployed as well.
With scope provided, you have to provide the swagger-springmvc jar, but also all its dependencies. Here, you need to provided classmate.jar.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, now i have a better understanding on how compile and provided works. Because the whole point of this is to reduce the size of the war by placing most of the commons jars in one folder I guess I have no choice but to look for and place all of swagger dependencies in tomcat's common lib folder although it's a bad practice.

Comment: Download [classmate-1.5.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.0/classmate-1.5.0.jar) or [classmate » 1.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.5.0) to resolve error.