# Failed to start service in Jboss7

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have failed deployment issue with Jboss7. I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": Failed to start service
```

My pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aa.xx.yy.cc</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core</name>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.63</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>dbre.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <!--
                      Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added
                      as default in the compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added
                      as default in the test-compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile
                      goal if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                    -->
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the error from the server log:

```
15:24:07,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit'
15:24:07,239 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/jandex/IndexView
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.jandex.IndexView from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @24f37f80 (roots: D:\Programmi\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 10 more

15:24:07,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit\": Failed to start service"}}
15:24:07,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war in 249ms
15:24:07,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."core-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#persistenceUnit": Failed to start service
```

I cannot find a solution to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Hibernate 4.2 using jandex and classmate if its Maven POM defines them as test scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168365/why-is-hibernate-4-2-using-jandex-and-classmate-if-its-maven-pom-defines-them-as)

Comment: I am not familiar with Java, but the `pom.xml` here is rather a large file for readers to wade through. Are you able to create a new project with a file of this kind with the smallest possible contents that reproduce the issue?

Comment: @halfer yes, my pom:

Comment: Sorry, were you intending to add more of a reply there? I was suggesting you cut down your failure example to the smallest possible case that still produces this error.